# C socket to handle full recv

Tags: c, sockets

Beej's guide/ tutorial on Socket Programming gives a readily usable snippet on sending all data over `send`. It is called `sendall` and is provided here - http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#sendall

No such definitive guidance is provided for `recv` all, even though it is stated that `recv` can be partial too. Why?

Also, how do a I write a non-blocking `recvall` function similar to the suggestion of `sendall`.  This seems like FAQ although there aren't simple answers available.

Comment: sendall() knows how much data it has to send.  Since plain TCP is a byte/octet streaming protocol, no such 'recvall' function is possible unless a message protocol on top of TCP is specified.

Comment: @MartinJames - Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to receive _all_ and also be _non blocking_?  I.e., what should the behavior be if only half of a message is available (and per Martin James, how does the receiver learn the intended message length?  is it fixed-length?)

Comment: My idea was to keep a global `char *buffer` of MAXSIZE, and keep doing `recv` and *append* the message to `char *buffer`until `recv` returns a 0.

Comment: How could you have a non-blocking recvall? You want to wait for 100 bytes to be received (for example), but you also don't want it to wait?

Comment: @immibis - Well, I think, I misstated my requirements. I can be blocking. I want a convenience method that blocks,  and gets the entire recv stream (till end is sent by the other end).

Comment: @SenthilKumaran right, so then you need to define what the 'end' is, and so that becomes part of your protocol definition:)

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea won't work.  `recv()` will block if it has read all of the bytes sent unless and until some more are sent.  If none are ever sent, you are stuck.  As the commenters above have stated, you need some way to tell when you have reached the end of the transmission.

There are two ways you could go.  The easiest way is to just close the socket at the sending end when you have sent all the data.  `recv()` will then return 0 in due course and you know that all the data you are expecting has arrived.

The other, slightly harder way, is to send the length of the message before the message itself.  This is simple enough.  At the sending end (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
uint32_t msg_len = ...;
uint32_t network_byte_order_msg_len = htonl (msg_len);
int nbytes = sizeof (network_byte_order_msg_len);
sendall (skt, sizeof (uint32_t), &network_byte_order_msg_len, &nbytes);
nbytes = msglen;
sendall (skt, my_msg_buf, &nbytes);
```

And at the receiving end, assuming we have a function `recv_bytes` which calls `recv` in a loop until it gets the number of bytes it's looking for:

```
uint32_t network_byte_order_msg_len;
int nbytes = sizeof (network_byte_order_msg_len);
recv_bytes (skt, &network_byte_order_msg_len, nbytes);
int msg_len = ntohl (&network_byte_order_msg_len);
void *msg_buf = malloc (msg_len);
nbytes = msg_len;
recv_bytes (skt, msg_buf, &nbytes);
```

Notice that by doing things this way we can allocate a message buffer of the right size in the receiver straight off the bat, which is nice and efficient.

You OK to write `recv_bytes()`?  Edit an implementation into my post if you like, for future visitors.

Edit: That code is C++, I'm sure you can fix it.